# Webpart properties are not loaded while provisioning webpart into page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, publishing-site

I have page layout where I have placed properties of the webpart in  . The webpart with the specified properties got provisioned in page. 
But the data in the webpart is displayed only after I click on edit webpart and click ok.This is publishing site.
Could you suggest me  ideas to overcome this.

Comment: What type of webpart is it? Custom or OOB?

Comment: Its OOB webpart.